# Adding recessed lights to existing non-recessed lights

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have a living room/dining room area that each only have 1 light - see photo.  The light over the table in controlled by its own switch, and the ceiling fan/light is controlled by another switch at another area.

I would like to add some recessed lighting to both zones. I'm thinking 4 in dining table area and 4-6 in the living room area.

How do I run the wiring in each case? I would think that I would disconnect existing light, make new holes for new recessed light and pull existing wire back to the closest hole to light switch, then try to run all 4 recessed light and existing dome light in series.

I have not done this before and have watched a ton of videos, read on the forums, etc, but still not sure how to best do this project. Looking for any advice you all might be able to share.
[image: at another]

Comment: Is this a two story or one story house?  In other words, do you have access to the top of the ceiling?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about 120V AC fixtures, you want to wire the light fixtures in parallel, not series. You would need a large accessible junction box for the connections if done the way you describe. Consider daisy chaining the fixtures instead, so that each light housing acts as a junction box.